# Getting an output with %s but %c is returning garbage value

Tags: c, arrays, character, structure

I wanted to accept the details of students(name,roll no. and marks) and print the same as output.The program is going fine if i accept the name as a string but i face problem when i accept the student's name as a character.
Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    struct student 
    {
        char name;
        int rn;
        float marks;
    };
    struct student s[2];
    int i;
    printf("Enter student's name,roll no. and marks:\n");
    for(i=1;i<=2;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",i);
        scanf("%c %d %f",&s[i].name,&s[i].rn,&s[i].marks);
    }
    printf("Student's name,roll no. and marks are:\n");
    for(i=1;i<=2;i++)
    printf("\nname=%c\trn=%d\tmarks=%0.2f\n\n",s[i].name,s[i].rn,s[i].marks);
}
```

Information of student 1 is completely correct.But facing problem in output of student 2.I just want to know what's actually happening in case of student 2.

Comment: You have correctly matched the field descriptor `%c` to the data type `char`, but `char` seems to be the wrong choice of data type.  It represents *one* character, whereas for a name, you probably want an array of `char` long enough to accommodate your maximum-length name.  Having switched to an array of char, you will want to also use field descriptor `%s`.

Comment: Indexing starts with 0 not 1.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes i understood but i want to use single character for name.Then how to do that?

Comment: @WebKing As mentioned by others firstly start index `i` from `0` and give whitespace before `%c`.

Comment: Thank you so much @achal and user3121023. Actually %c was considering next line as a character.Problem got solved when i gave one space before %c in scanf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*i face problem when i accept the student's name as a character ?* Thats because `scanf()` is line buffered i.e when you enter *one char* and then you press *ENTER* key, that is also one valid char so you are giving two char as a input. To avoid this  buffering problem give the whitespace before `%c`. for e.g

```
for(i = 0;i < 2;i++) { /* also you had s[2] means, you should start from  i = 0  */ 
        scanf(" %c%d%f",&s[i].name,&s[i].rn,&s[i].marks);
}
```

The main problem is `for(i=1;i<=2;i++)` as you are starting from `s[1]` and expecting to store into `s[2]` also but there is no `s[2]`  as you declared 
`struct student s[2];` that means `s[0]` & `s[1]`, solution is start from `i = 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
for(i=1;i<=2;i++)
```

to this:

```
for(i=0; i < 2; i++)
```

since indexing starts from 0 to the size of your array, minus 1.

Answer (score 0):

Struct is a value type and it holds single memory block on stack. So 1 char holds (depending on system) 1 character like 'M'. In order to keep name you need a pointer or array of characters. This way you are storing only 1 character and after that one some random memory junk occurs because you are referencing out of bounds value which is in this case just 1 character.

Comment: Then why this memory junk is not occuring in case of student 1?

Comment: You are applying & operator which is an address operator. In a nutshell it will create a pointer to memory location and you are referencing that location when writing student name. This is on stack - a pointer to starting address of char. That is whole difference. In first case you are reffering to memory location rather then value itself. That causes char to be treated as char* from scanf function perspective. Hope it helps.